# Ajax JSON access array from the array JSON encode server respond

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array JSON encode respond when the ajax JSON throw a post request (refer below).

`requestparser.php`:

```
$array = array("phweb" => "yes", "phemail" => "yeeess");
echo json_encode($array);
```

And this Ajax JSON use for sending post request to `requestparser.php` and processing the return response.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'requestparser.php',
        data: { "request" : "pull" },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
        alert(result[0]);
        alert(result[1]);
        }
});
```

I want to get the value of array key `phweb` and the value of array key `phemail` yet when an alert box popup, it says `undefined`. What seems the problem? Any help, ideas, clues would be greatly appreciated.

So far what I tried is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'requestparser.php',
    data: { "request" : "pull" },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
    alert(result[0]->phweb);
    alert(result[1]->phemail);
    }
});
```

And sadly, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is a JSON object. You can access it like this

```
success: function(result) {
    alert(result['phweb']);
    alert(result['phemail']);
}
```

Comment: please mark it as answered it your question is solved

Comment: how about if multidimensional arrays (arrays inside an arrays)? like this. "  $array = array("phweb" => array("ph" => $status, "phemail" => $status2));
                         echo json_encode($array);" how to do it then?

Comment: you can do `result['phweb']['ph']`

Comment: how about get the array key? how to do that?

Comment: you mean getting `"phweb"` ?

Comment: no, i want to get the arrary key name that hold the array phweb and phemail.

Comment: result is the object that holds the phweb and phemail; It just had a key and  a value. `result : { phweb: '---', 'phemail': '--'} ` this is how it looks. So it won't have key. Result itself is a key